# Video on demand website's server setup

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, video-on-demand

I want to build middle scale anime-video watching website. For this purpose I am researching.

-I want to host my own videos, episodes of animes. I dont want to use some Russian video service.

-So for this purpose I want to understand how the media websites, cdns works together. I did lots of googling but it didnt come with an answer.

-For example, Should I buy two dedicated server and one for website and one for storage. And how should these servers communicate each other?

-Solutions like Amazon AWS, Wowza are not for my budget. I am searching low costs solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I advise you to use at least 2 servers, 1 for streaming/Storage and other for the Web stuff, the streaming solution use a lot of resources that could hang the server and if you keep your website on the same you will be completely off line when this happen.

For streaming you can use free software like ffmpeg, nginx (with RTMP module) or VLC,you could build a great platform with these softwares but the learning curve is slow. 
For me Wowza is the best, but you need to pay $65/month per server.

On the web side, to show the videos I recommend to use [flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org) because it use html5 and flash fallback, is very easy to implement and is free.

Well, you have a lot work to do, best luck.